# Specific gem install for my Projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, 12factor

I need the rails_12factor gem to install into my gem file for my app in order to successfully deploy to Heroku. I was able to to install the gem (gem install rails_12factor) and if I run gem list it shows that it is installed locally. How do I get that particular gem to be installed in my bundle? Not sure if I am asking this right but as you can see below it is installed locally as I stated.

```
4.0.0)
actionpack (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
activemodel (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
addressable (2.3.5)
arel (4.0.1)
atomic (1.1.14)
bigdecimal (1.2.3, 1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
excon (0.30.0, 0.25.3)
execjs (2.0.2)
heroku-api (0.3.15)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (1.5.2)
jquery-rails (3.0.4)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
launchy (2.4.2, 2.4.1)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (2.0, 1.25.1, 1.25)
minitest (5.0.8, 4.7.5, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.8.2)
mysql2 (0.3.14)
netrc (0.7.7)
pg (0.17.0 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.2, 2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
**rails_12factor (0.0.2)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)**
railties (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.1, 4.0.0, 3.12.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubygems-update (2.1.11)
rubyzip (1.1.0)
sass (3.2.12)
sass-rails (4.0.1)
sdoc (0.3.20)
sprockets (2.10.1)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.8 x86-mingw32)
test-unit (2.5.5, 2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
turbolinks (1.3.1)
tzinfo (1.1.0, 0.3.38)
uglifier (2.3.1)

However it is not in my bundle below:

c:\dev\project2>bundle

Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.5)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.2)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.0)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.0)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
Using activemodel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord (4.0.0)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.0)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using jbuilder (1.5.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using mysql2 (0.3.14)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.1)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using sass (3.2.12)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using turbolinks (1.3.1)
Using uglifier (2.3.1)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I am able to find rails_12factor-0.02.gemspec in this path C:\Users\vern.gem\specs\rubygems.org%443\quick\Marshal.4.8

I notice it's a gem spec file however I do not know how to get it installed as part of my gem bundle for my project

Below is what I get when I push to heroku:

```
c:\dev\project2>git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/vern/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 87, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Writing objects: 100% (87/87), 16.24 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 87 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bund
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.5)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.8.2)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Installing activesupport (4.0.0)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing actionpack (4.0.0)
       Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Installing activemodel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.1)
       Installing activerecord (4.0.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Installing mysql2 (0.3.14)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.10.1)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Installing rails (4.0.0)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using sass (3.2.12)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
       Using sdoc (0.3.20)
       Using turbolinks (1.3.1)
       Using uglifier (2.3.1)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (17.19s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Removing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Removing kgio (2.8.1)
       Removing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Removing jbuilder (1.5.1)
       Removing raindrops (0.12.0)
       Removing activerecord (3.2.14)
       Removing builder (3.0.4)
       Removing rails (3.2.14)
       Removing activesupport (3.2.14)
       Removing actionmailer (3.2.14)
       Removing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Removing unicorn (4.6.3)
       Removing mime-types (1.25)
       Removing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.2)
       Removing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Removing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Removing execjs (2.0.1)
       Removing json (1.8.0)
       Removing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Removing rack-cache (1.2)
       Removing puma (2.6.0)
       Removing journey (1.0.4)
       Removing activesupport (4.0.1)
       Removing activemodel (4.0.1)
       Removing activemodel (3.2.14)
       Removing sass (3.2.10)
       Removing nokogiri (1.6.0)
       Removing multi_json (1.8.0)
       Removing actionpack (4.0.1)
       Removing uglifier (2.2.1)
       Removing railties (3.2.14)
       Removing rails (4.0.1)
       Removing arel (3.0.2)
       Removing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Removing rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Removing activeresource (3.2.14)
       Removing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
       Removing actionmailer (4.0.1)
       Removing sprockets (2.10.0)
       Removing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Removing mini_portile (0.5.1)
       Removing activerecord (4.0.1)
       Removing pg (0.17.0)
       Removing rack (1.4.5)
       Removing actionpack (3.2.14)
       Removing railties (4.0.1)
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2013-11-29T23:11:27.829492 #1297]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_55e1f130-6b0f-4106-871a-45
lic/assets/application-fee71c53d09a01d2ff7501990d2c3307.js
       I, [2013-11-29T23:11:27.856160 #1297]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_55e1f130-6b0f-4106-871a-45
lic/assets/application-96a552b03ca0e7ebcbfc44b89ca097a6.css
       Asset precompilation completed (7.77s)
       Cleaning assets
-----> WARNINGS:
       Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.

       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 21.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v5
       http://fast-lake-6950.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:fast-lake-6950.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

c:\dev\project2>
```

As you can see it removes the rails_12 factor gem so I am not quite sure what to do. I also get the warning

WARNINGS:
           Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
           See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information. Perhaps there is a solution that I did not realize any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Ruby Version 2.0.0
Rails 4.0.0
Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting `rails_12factor` gem only in production

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

So this will not install the gem in your development environment but will do it in your production environment (when you push to heroku).

Hope this helps